# RecyclerView in Fragments Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a navigation drawer in main screen with couple fragments.
In main (default) fragment I have 2 recyclerviews. In profile fragment, I have 3 recyclerviews within 3 tabs.

Normally, I did not get "Error inflating" or "skipping layout" errors when I use Recyclerview, but I have always problem in fragments.

In normal usage, its all okey but when I go inside and outside of fragments one by one, I got "Error inflating class" and it points to Adapter's onCreateViewHolder (view = Layoutinflater....)

**Navigation Activity**

```
public class Page_Navigation extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Fragment fragment;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
NavigationView navigationView;

SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
DrawerLayout drawer;
private Tracker mTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page__navigation);

    //
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView toolbar_head = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_head);
    ImageView toolbar_image = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_image);
    ImageView toolbar_profile = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_profile);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //

    AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.setScreenName("page_navigation");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    //FIRST SETTINGS
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Montserrat-Medium.ttf");
    toolbar_head.setTypeface(customFont);

    //Get Sessions
    mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String session_user_name = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_name", "");
    String session_user_photo = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_photo", "");

    //Navigation Drawer
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    //

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView nav_userName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nav_userName);
    CircleImageView imageView_navigation = (CircleImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_navigation);
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(session_user_photo).into(imageView_navigation);
    nav_userName.setText(session_user_name);

    headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showProfileFragment();
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    });


    toolbar_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    toolbar_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment;
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment = new Nav_Profile();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
    displayDefaultFragment();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page__navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    final int id = item.getItemId();


    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new Nav_Home();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_contact:
                    fragment = new Nav_Contact();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_articles:
                    fragment = new Nav_Article();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_about:
                    fragment = new Nav_AboutUs();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_suggest:
                    fragment = new Nav_Suggest();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_share:
                    fragment = new Nav_Share();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_rateApp:
                    fragment = new Nav_RateApp();
                    break;


            }

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.navContent, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        }
    }, 350);


    return true;
}

public void displayDefaultFragment() {
    fragment = new Nav_Home();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).commit();

}

public void showSuggestFragment() {
    fragment = new Nav_Profile();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

public void showProfileFragment() {
    fragment = new Nav_Profile();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

public void setFontNavigation() {
    Menu m = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem mi = m.getItem(i);

        //for applying a font to subMenu ...
        SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
        if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                SpannableString s = new SpannableString(subMenuItem.getTitle());
                s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("font/mont_regular.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                subMenuItem.setTitle(s);
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

**First(Default) Fragment of Navigation**

```
public class Nav_Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

SharedPreferences mSharedPref;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh_home;

private CardView item_homeTop_coupons, item_homeTop_draws, item_homeTop_event;
private LinearLayout layout_all_article, layout_all_999;
private ScrollView shimmer_home;

private List<Model_ListItem> listNewItems;
private RecyclerView recyclerView_item_home;

private List<Model_Article> articleList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView_article_home;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav__home, container, false);
    item_homeTop_coupons = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_coupons);
    item_homeTop_draws = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_draws);
    item_homeTop_event = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_event);
    recyclerView_item_home = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_item_home);
    recyclerView_article_home = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_article_home);
    layout_all_article = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_all_article);
    layout_all_999 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_all_999);
    swipeRefresh_home = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_home);
    shimmer_home = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_home);
    item_homeTop_coupons.setOnClickListener(this);
    item_homeTop_draws.setOnClickListener(this);
    item_homeTop_event.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout_all_999.setOnClickListener(this);
    layout_all_article.setOnClickListener(this);

    //first settngs
    mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
    String session_user_email = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_email","");


    swipeRefresh_home.setRefreshing(true);

    fetchItemsNew();
    fetchArticlesNew();


    return view;
}


public void openProfileFragment(){
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragment = new Nav_Profile();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.item_homeTop_coupons:
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Coupon.class));
            break;

        case R.id.item_homeTop_draws:
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Draw.class));
            break;

        case R.id.item_homeTop_event:
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Event.class));
            break;

        case R.id.layout_all_999:
            //999 city search activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_SearchCity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.layout_all_article:
            //article fragment
            Fragment fragment;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragment = new Nav_Article();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;


    }
}

public void seeSession(){

    //sessions
    mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    String session_user_id = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_id", "");
    String session_user_email = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_email", "");
    String session_user_name = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_name", "");
    String session_user_image = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_image", "");
    String session_user_nickname = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_nickname", "");


}

public void fetchItemsNew(){
    listNewItems = new ArrayList<>();
    API_Service api_service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);
    Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call = api_service.fetchItemsNew();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model_ListItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call, Response<List<Model_ListItem>> response) {

            if(response.code() == 200){

                listNewItems = response.body();


                recyclerView_item_home.setHasFixedSize(true);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerView_item_home.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                Adapter_HomeItem adapter_homeItem = new Adapter_HomeItem(getContext(), listNewItems);
                recyclerView_item_home.setAdapter(adapter_homeItem);
                SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
                helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView_item_home);



            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}

public void fetchArticlesNew(){
    articleList = new ArrayList<>();
    API_Service api_service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);
    Call<List<Model_Article>> callArticle = api_service.fetchArticlesNew();
    callArticle.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model_Article>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model_Article>> call, Response<List<Model_Article>> response) {

            if(response.code() == 200){

                articleList = response.body();


                recyclerView_article_home.setHasFixedSize(true);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerView_article_home.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                Adapter_HomeArticles adapter_homeArticles = new Adapter_HomeArticles(getContext(), articleList);
                recyclerView_article_home.setAdapter(adapter_homeArticles);
                if(swipeRefresh_home.isRefreshing()){
                    swipeRefresh_home.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                shimmer_home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                swipeRefresh_home.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Model_Article>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class Adapter_HomeItem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_HomeItem.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Model_ListItem> homeList;
String urlExtension = URL_Extension.url_extension_images;

public Adapter_HomeItem(Context context, List<Model_ListItem> homeList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.homeList = homeList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)     {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Glide.with(context).load(urlExtension+homeList.get(position).getItem_image()).into(holder.item_home_image);
    holder.item_home_text.setText(homeList.get(position).getItem_name());

    holder.item_home_cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //item detail
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Page_ItemDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("itemClicked", ""+homeList.get(position).getItem_id());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return homeList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView item_home_cardView;
    RoundedImageView item_home_image;
    TextView item_home_text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        item_home_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_home_text);
        item_home_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_home_image);
        item_home_cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_home_cardView);
    }
}

}
```

**Error was here;**

```
public Adapter_HomeArticles.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_article, null);
    int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth()/3;
    view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

**Throws;**

```
  06-28 17:20:08.543 23120-23120/? E/Zygote: v2
06-28 17:20:08.543 23120-23120/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-28 17:20:10.468 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:20:10.473 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:05.018 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:10.423 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:11.108 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:11.628 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:16.288 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:17.533 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:19.008 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@7c57e67
06-28 17:23:19.013 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6446414
    motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@6446414
06-28 17:23:20.643 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:22.738 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:24.468 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:27.818 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-28 17:23:28.118 23120-23120/turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android, PID: 23120
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android.Adapter.Adapter_HomeArticles.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter_HomeArticles.java:39)
        at turkiyedeyapilacak999sey.android.Adapter.Adapter_HomeArticles.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter_HomeArticles.java:25)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:258)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2104)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:510)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving `null` instead of `false` in place of root:

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_home_list, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: @keremoflu4 remove parent parameter too. Look at the edited answer.

Comment: I tried in all adapters, but after couple test now it gives error to this line of default (first) home fragment
` View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav__home, container, false);`

Comment: After a test, now it shows one of recyclerview within that fragment. As same line view = inflater etc. (I set null as you said)

I edited throws to post.

Comment: looking at your logs I think you are giving a wrong name or using a wrong attribute to in your row xml file.

Comment: Item XMLs are true because it shows me the items in recyclerview which comes from rest api. I found what occurs but didnt solve. When I call "home" fragment with clicking navigation drawer like 6-7 times, this occurs. Also sometimes error is pointing to home fragment's view = inflater.inflate.... line.
I'm really confused

Comment: @keremoflu4 now I get it. when you continuously click like 5-6 times it crashes right ? This happens because the fragment is not yet destroyed and you are clicking another one then another click so it gets destroyed. Just put a check that once your one fragment is destroyed then you will be able to move to next.

Comment: How kind of code I need. I also use addToBackStack for fragments to go back. By the way even though how much time I click the menu, this only occurs for home fragment.

Comment: @keremoflu4 you need to debug your code :) I am sure you will know I reason I can't tell you when it occurs so please debug and I am sure you will find the problem

Comment: Okey, I will try thanks, last question. Do you think adding fragments to back stack occur memory leak and I might get this for it? (android profiler looks well)

Comment: @keremoflu4 no adding fragments to back stack is for saving their state so that you can access them whenever you want. If you get them out of backStack then every fragment will be initialized again and again. And no the problem is not backstack but something else.